# How to call a python built-in function in c++ with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am using pybind11 to call a python built-in function like range in c++ code. But I only found way to call a function in module like this:

```
py::object os = py::module::import("os");
py::object makedirs = os.attr("makedirs");
makedirs("/tmp/path/to/somewhere");
```

But a python built-in function like range needn't import any modules, so how can I use pybind11 to call range in c++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fetch `range` from the [`globals` dict](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=globals#_CPPv47globalsv).

Answer (score 0):

You can also import the `builtins` module which contains all the built-in python functions.

In your case it would be something like:

```
py::object builtins = py::module_::import("builtins");
py::object range = builtins.attr("range");
range(0, 10);
```